# Changing contents of iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I am having an html page consisting of an iframe:

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe id = "i1" name = "i1" src = "C:\Documents and Settings\adivekar\Desktop\sa.html"></iframe>
<br><input type = "text" name = "t1" id = "One"/>
<br><input type = "button" value = "change1" name = "b1" onclick = "call1()">
<script type = "text/javascript">
function call1(){
    var a = document.getElementById('i1');
    var b = a.contentDocument;
    b.open()
    var c = b.getElementById('Two');
    c.value = "dfsdf";  
}
</script>
</body>
```

The page containing iframe is:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type = "text" name = "t2" id = "Two"/>

</body>
</html>
```

I am unable to update the value of textbox in the iframe.

Comment: Do you get an error? I could imagine it does not work because of the same origin policy. The content you load is of another domain...

Answer (score 2):

If the iframe doesn't come from the same domain as the main document, you will not be able to access the iframe's document. If it does, your code should work in most browsers. I'd change it slightly for browsers that don't support the `contentDocument` property of ifame elements, and remove the call to the iframe document's `open()` method, which is unnecessary and possibly problematic:

```
function call1(){
    var a = document.getElementById('i1');
    var b = a.contentDocument || a.contentWindow.document;
    var c = b.getElementById('Two');
    c.value = "dfsdf";  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementById('i1').getElementById('Two').value = "..";
```

Comment: This will not work. An iframe element is not its own document object.